# Selected for/to + ing

Tags: complementation

Would you write

> He has been selected **for testing** the car

OR

> He has been selected **to test** the car

OR

> He has been selected **to testing** the best car ever made

Comment: He has been selected to test the best car ever made.

Answer (score 2):

> He has been selected for testing the car.

The above is grammatically correct.  You are using the present participle as a noun as *testing* becomes a gerund.

> He has been selected to test the car.

Also right, this is what most people would say.

> He has been selected to testing the best car ever made.

The phrase "to testing" is both grammatically and semantically wrong.