# Stayed at home ‘for cooking/to cook’

Tags: gerunds

Thank you guys,
As a non-native speaker, I wondered which one sounds more naturally. (in academic writing)

1. Mothers, traditionally, stayed at home to cook and look after their children.
2. Mothers, traditionally, stayed at home for cooking and looking after their children.

Thank you very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selected for/to + ing](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/78036/selected-for-to-ing)

Comment: In academic writing, I’d prefer #1. But #2 is still grammatical. You could eliminate the _for_ in #2 and use a comma instead: _Mothers traditionally stayed at home, cooking and looking after their children_.

Comment: Cooking their children seems a bit cruel, doesn't it?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey pretty funny, like the joke about "Let's eat Grandma!" with the missing comma.

Comment: In 1990 when Britain was introducing a local tax (the "poll tax")  based on the number of occupants in each house, the Daily Mail had an article about filling out the tax form headed "What to do about Granny? Put her down." Maybe you have to be a Brit to see why that is funny, I'm not sure.

Comment: King Charles walked and talked half an hour after his head was cut off.

Answer (score 1):

It's more natural to say "(they) stayed home *to* ..."

However, as Michael Harvey points in his comment, the funny bit is the phrasing of the last part of the sentence which invites an unwanted parallel between "cook" and "look after".  For example:

> I stayed home from practice today to **clean** and **polish** my new car.

Here both actions are *implicitly* being done to the car.  In the same way:

> ... to **cook** and **look after** their children

can be humorously misinterpreted as "to *cook* their children" and "to look after their children".

Of course, no one will think that is what you meant, but if you want to avoid any misunderstanding, simply include the preposition:

> Mothers, traditionally, stayed at home to cook **for** and look after their children.

(Side note)  Peter's suggestion to substitute "care for" in place of "look after" is fine, but in my opinion it doesn't really clarify the meaning.  The combination of *mothers* with *look after* is common in English writing.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence might be better expressed as

> Mothers, traditionally, stayed at home to cook and **care** for their children.

"***Look after***" can have more of a babysitting meaning of just "***watching out for***", and in this case the first sentence is the better choice.